# My First Add-A-Gram

Tags: word, anagram

Well, I've looked at a bunch of puzzles here but I'm not good at making long involved ones, so I'll make a short one:

**A bad word** inside a **suffix of a Chinese martial art** inside an **alien spaceship** inside **one tenth of a Biblical flood** inside a **gathering place**.

Comment: Nothing wrong at all with a short puzzle. They don't all have to be mind blowers! :) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:-

a bad word

> f

suffix of a Chinese martial art

> fu

alien spaceship

> ufo

one tenth of a Biblical flood

> four

gathering place

> forum

Comment: I was hoping it would take someone longer to get than it took me to create T_T  I at least thought the 4th clue would throw people off.

Comment: Haha whoops sorry. The third clue was too easy. And I just built upwards and downwards from it. Helped that the third clue was the middle one.